# Android, cannot be cast in setOnItemClickListener

Tags: java, android

I want to use this line of code I've seen in several examples:

```
    lvRadios.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) lvRadios.getItemAtPosition(position);
            int idRadio = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID"));
            Log.i("ID", String.valueOf(idRadio));

            ShowResults(position, view);
        }
    });
```

But I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.database.Cursor
```

I'm using Android 6.0 with Android Studio 2.1.2

I hope you can help me.

Regards.

Comment: Please read the documentation to see what `getItemAtPosition` returns. Tip: it most likely is not a Cursor, so casting it won't work

Answer (score 1):

Your error is telling you that you're trying to turn a string into a cursor. For the operation you're performing, you wouldn't get a cursor. You would get a UI element or something tied to a UI element.

Comment out what you already have inside of the `onItemClick` and replace it with:

```
String radioString = (String) lvRadios.getItemAtPosition(position);

//Debug: Show a toast to see what information you're getting
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), radioString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

Then, you can do what you want once you know the result.